# Long boot after upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: boot, systemd

Its take much longer after the upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 but its not the case when i boot from a live USB.
Do I need to purge or reinstall anything?
I prefer the systemd method and I have the dmesg out in here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10898960/

Edit bodhi.zazen - link to systemd-analyze blame output http://paste.ubuntu.com/10899690/

Top processes taking the longest time

> ```
>      9.157s systemd-udev-settle.service
>       9.071s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f9aaa205\x2d239f\x2d4504\x2d8b3d\x2dee806c50780a.device
>       7.474s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
>       3.537s systemd-udevd.service
>       3.148s plymouth-quit-wait.service
>       3.090s gpu-manager.service
>       2.975s apparmor.service
>       2.116s apache2.service
>       2.105s mysql.service
>       1.343s systemd-modules-load.service
>       1.341s NetworkManager.service
>       1.116s ModemManager.service
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To identify the problem, run;

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Or for graphical analysis

```
systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg
eog plot.svg
```

Use any viewer if you do not use eog ;)

Other distros (Fedora and Arch) have been using systemd for longer, and have IMO better documentation then Ubuntu at the moment.

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_boot_performance

Optimization may include disabling services you do not need, for example see

https://harald.hoyer.xyz/2013/11/13/fedora-boot-optimization/

Once you have identified where the boot is hanging or taking too long you can look into solutions.

See also http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/systemd-bootchart.1.html

I really can not find ubuntu specific information on the ubuntu wiki as of yet.

Comment: Absolute useless answer in a hurry by assuming the word "long boot" in my query. Have you made an assessment of my log file to know whether it is due to slowness?

Comment: log file did not explain slow boot and if you need assistance post the result of `systemd-analyze blame`

Comment: Now that is talking. Here you go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10899690/

Comment: so now you know what processes are taking the longest. Unfortunately you  will have to either wait for someone with more experience with systemd and ubuntu to answer or start looking at the arch and fedora dcoumentation to see what, if anything you can adjust. I do not mess much with my fedora boot time as it generally causes more issues then it is worth, IMO. Be warned, as you know Ubuntu is not Fedora or arch so hard to know how to adapt some of  the advice to Ubuntu and again I can not find any ubuntu specific documentation on this topic in a google search.

Comment: Point taken.Appreciate your effort and time. Cheers.

Comment: It will get better as more people gain experience with systemd on ubuntu.