# Ubuntu 15.04 is booting very slowly

Tags: boot, 15.04

Ubuntu 15.04 is booting very slowly. I tried with dmesg output but couldn't understand which items were problems/issues actually. [Here](http://pastebin.com/NX5kEFX7) is dmesg output. Someone please help me!

**EDIT 1**
Here is the `systemd-analyze critical-chain` output. `wpa_supplicant` and `kerneloops` are killing time I guess! Any suggestion?

```
graphical.target @1min 10.998s
└─multi-user.target @1min 10.997s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 10.869s +128ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 10.868s
      └─network.target @1min 849ms
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 1.140s +192ms
          └─basic.target @57.119s
            └─sockets.target @57.118s
              └─avahi-daemon.socket @57.118s
                └─sysinit.target @57.109s
                  └─networking.service @56.947s +162ms
                    └─apparmor.service @56.105s +839ms
                      └─local-fs.target @56.104s
                        └─run-cgmanager-fs.mount @57.234s
                          └─local-fs-pre.target @55.259s
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @55.211s +35ms
                              └─systemd-fsck-root.service @55.103s +106ms
                                └─systemd-fsckd.socket @1.781s
                                  └─-.slice @1.690s
```

Comment: How new is your installation, which is to say, how long ago did you install it and how many times have you rebooted it since it was installed?

Comment: See other questions for how to ask these questions better _on a version 15 system such as yours_, complete with the reports generated by `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` included in the questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/626115/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/614349/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/623799/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/

Comment: ``wpa_supplicant`` and ``kerneloops`` are killing time I guess! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now my machine is booting in 30 sec. I just issued the following command:

```
systemctl mask systemd-udev-settle
```

I visualize using `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg` ([output](http://s9.postimg.org/78391wfdr/plot.png)) and found `systemd-udev-settle` to take a minute. Then masking helped me a lot.

Thank you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many people have had this same issue before. I'm positive that it is a bug in the current build of Mate. If you don't know much about code, then try another build of Mate. If the boot time is faster, then reply back.

Comment: I'll try and post here, thanks for your suggestion.